# String formatting, trim from right instead of left

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of strings that I want to format to keep the string at 5 characters. I'm using a line like this (the original strings are sometimes 5 characters, sometimes 6):

```
ram1 = ram1.astype('|S5')
```

However, this turns

```
039410
```

Into

```
39410
```

When I want it to be

```
03941
```

Is there a simple way to fix my line of code to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: Works fine for me, what version of numpy?

Comment: Strings don't have `astype`, your example doesn't work.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, numpy does

Comment: @uhurol, what is the dtype of the original array?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's imported as a string then .astype into integer

Comment: @uhurulol, ah ok, mystery solved then, you are losing the leading 0 when you cast to int, `np.array(["039410"]).astype(int)
 -> array([39410])
`, if you want to keep leading 0's then you will need to keep them as strings

Answer (score 4):

You can use `format`:

```
ram1 = '3941'
print '{0:0>5s}'.format(ram1)
## 03941
```

where the characters after `:` describe the format (0-padded 5-character long string).

You can also use `zfill`:

```
print ram1.zfill(5)
## 03941
```

In case you need to truncate your string, you can use the following format:

```
print '{:.5s}'.format('039410')
## 03941
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oops, i don't know how i had missed that. thanks. It is now corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned `astype`, it appears `ram` is a NumPy array.

To remove all `0`s from the right size of each value, use [`np.char.rstrip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html):

```
np.char.rstrip(ram, '0')
```

To preserve just the first 5 bytes for each value,

```
ram.astype('|S5')
```

suffices.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
ram = np.array(['039410', '123456', '00000']).astype('|S6')
print(np.char.rstrip(ram, b'0'))
# ['03941' '123456' '']

print(ram.view('|S5'))
# ['03941' '12345' '00000']
```

---

As [Padraic Cunningham points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148487/string-formatting-trim-from-right-instead-of-left/37148849?noredirect=1#comment61836083_37148487), if you have an array of strings:

```
In [209]: ram = np.array(['039410', '123456', '00000']).astype('|S6'); ram
Out[209]: 
array([b'039410', b'123456', b'00000'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

and convert the strings to ints, you lose zeros on the left:

```
In [210]: ram.astype(int)
Out[210]: array([ 39410, 123456,      0])
```

So do not use `astype(int)` if you wish to preserve the first 5 bytes of the string.

Comment: I am not going mad then, what original dtype would make it not work?

Comment: Maybe the OP has an array of integers: `array([39410, 12345, 0])`. Then `ram.astype('|S5')` returns `array([b'39410', b'12345', b'0'], dtype='|S5')`.

Comment: That was what I thought too but 9 is not valid in octal, maybe they `int("039410")` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with numpy array containing string then astype will work fine.

```
string = np.array('039410')
print string          
## 039410
string = string.astype('|S5')
print string
## 03941
```

If you are working on list of strings then you should do this.

```
str_list = ['039410']
index = 0
for i in str_list:
    i = i[:5]
    str_list[index] = i
    index += 1
print str_list
## ['03941']
```

If you are working on single string then you just have to do this

```
str_num = '039410'
str_num = str_num[:5]
print str_num
## '03941'
```

Answer (score -1):

if the string length is not less than 5 character then you can use the below code

```
a = "abcdef"

print a[0:5]
```